# How can I trigger a transition when moving from one page to another using CSS?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to add animated transitions that are triggered when moving from one page to another, using CSS only, no JavaScript, jQuery, or any other script. I researched this quite a bit and from what I've seen, most transitions use the hover pseudo-class or require some script.  I used CSS3 keyframes and it worked, but I think I'm supposed to just use the transition property if it's possible. 
I tried using the pseudo-classes :active and :target but it seems to just change when I click the link, it's not a transition that occurs while moving to the other page. How can I trigger a transition when moving from one page to another using only CSS?

Here's the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<nav class="sitenavigation">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="link1.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="link2.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="link3.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="link4.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="link5.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="link6.html">Text</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>`
```

CSS:

```
nav.sitenavigation:a 
{
text-align: center;
margin: 0.5em 0.7em 0.5em 0.7em;
font-size: 1.15em; 
color: #f0f5f5; 
background-color: #75a3a3;
font-family: Merienda;

-webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 1.5s ease;
transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:active, nav.sitenavigation a:target {
color: #293d3d;  
}
```

Comment: You can't have a transition running while you load another page. As soon as you clicked the link, the old page shuts down and the new starts to load. If to use AJAX to load would be different though, but that is script.

Comment: You can't have pure CSS transitions between multiple pages. You can achieve the desired effect one of two ways - either **hide** sections of content in a single page and animate those, or use an SPA JavaScript framework like AngularJS, Backbone or Ember to transition between multiple pages. AJAX is a third option, but it's again done with JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought. Is it possible to have a pure CSS transition from one content section to another that gets triggered when a user scrolls?

Comment: No, not without script